# How to test if a variable is equal to a number in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

I have this shell script that isn't working.

Input:

```
Server_Name=1
if [ $Server_Name=1 ]; then  
echo Server Name is 1  
else
echo Server Name is not 1
fi
```

Output:

```
Server Name is 1
```

But, if i change `Server_Name=2`, the output is:

```
Server Name is 1
```

When I change `Server_Name` to `2`, I want it to say: `Server Name is 2`.

I know it is the `if [ $Server_Name=1 ];` part.

How do i fix it?

Comment: As David points out below, you must use "-eq" to test numeric values.  You might also want to check for a blank variable to avoid errors; `if [ ! "x$var"  = "x" ]; then\n if [ $var -eq 1 ]; then ...`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Your script indicates you are using string comparisons.

Assume server name could be a string instead of number only.

For **String comparisons**:
`if [[ "$Server_Name" == 1 ]]; then`

**Notes:**

- Spacing around == is a **must**
- Spacing around = is a **must**
  `if [ $Server_Name=1 ]; then` is WRONG
- [[ ... ]] reduces errors as no pathname expansion or word splitting takes place between [[ and ]]
- Prefer quoting strings that are "words"

For **Integer comparisons**:
`if [[ "$Server_Name" -eq 1 ]]; then`

---

More information:

- [Bash Comparison Operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)
- [SO: What is the difference between operator “=” and “==” in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600281/what-is-the-difference-between-operator-and-in-bash)
- [Unix & Linux SE: Bash: double equals vs -eq](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16109/bash-double-equals-vs-eq)

Comment: `[[` is bash syntax and the OP was asking about shell, where it wouldn't work

Comment: I agree with @gilad905. Please use `if [ "$Server_Name" = "1" ]` or even `if [ "$Server_Name" -eq "1" ]` for comparing numeric value (would still work if `Server_Name` is defined with `=01`).

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
if [ $Server_Name -eq 1 ];then
```

Comment: Maybe write with quotes `"$Server_Name"` to be safe from any corner cases where the variable would contain spaces or other wild data.

Answer (score 2):

```
[ $Server_Name=1 ]
```

does not work as intended because the syntax inside the single brackets isn't special to Bash. As usual, the variable `$Server_Name` gets substituted by 1, so all the *test* (`[`) command sees is a single argument: the string `1=1`. Since that sting has a non-zero length, *test* returns *true*.

For POSIX-compliant shells, you can use the following *test* commands:

```
[ "$Server_Name" = 1 ]
```

checks is the `$Server_Name` is equal to the string `1`.

```
[ "$Server_Name" -eq 1 ]
```

checks is the `$Server_Name` is equal to the **number** `1`, i.e., it does a numeric comparison instead of a string comparison.

The return value of the two command will differ, e.g., if you define `Server_Name=01`. The first one will return false, the second will return true.

Note that if the possibility exists that the variable `$Server_Name` is undefined, it **must** be quoted or *test* will display an error when invoked.

Answer (score -1):

Try,

```
 #!/bin/bash
 Server_Name=50
 if [ $Server_Name = 49 ]
 then
 echo "Server Name is 50"
 else
 echo "Server Name is below 50"
 fi
```

output:

```
 #./scriptname.sh
 Server Name is below 50
```

Comment: This code messages are just untrue: `if is 49, print "is 50"?!!`, `if not equal to 49, print "is below 50"`?!!!

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer. Your code is correct - almost. the only thing you are missing is spaces... (and well maybe an extra "=")

```
if [ $Server_Name=1 ]; then
```

will not compute correctly.

```
if [ $Server_Name == 1 ]; then
```

is what you seek.

And now the statement about string versus numbers. Whenever you are searching for comparison like is / is-not, then == will always be fine.

And i assume you always have a server name as a string, not a number - right? ;-)

Good luck with your coding sturdy apprentice.

Ciao

Comment: `==` is **not** a *standard* way to test the value of a variable in shell! Use the `test` command (aka `[`).